# cakephp - How to display options from a table as radio button

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an application where the user can de-activate his account by passing in some comments.

```
**Table # Deactivate_Lkup**
Id   Reason
1    Did not like the site!
2    My account is compromised.
3    I want to open a new account.
```

I want to display the above values from the table on a screen as radio button and want to save the user selected option along with some comments in the database in the user table or in an associated user table.

Any code snippets or examples will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
/**
 * Get list of Reasons
 */
$options = $this->Deactivate_Lkup->find('list', array(
  'fields' => array(
    'Deactivate_Lkup.Reason'
  )
));

$this->set('options', $options);
```

View:

```
/**
 * Output 'Reasons' as radio buttons
 */
echo $this->Form->radio('Reason', $options);
```

I notice you're not using the database naming conventions that Cake prefers so I would also consider changing that as well. Take a look at: [CakePHP Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)